# How to add multiple values to react hook without rendering the view

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm working on a react native project.

I want to add multiple images in the useState hook without re-setting the state of the hook.

**eg: I want to capture an image using the camera and update the hook with the file path (this is okay at the moment), then I want to capture another image through the camera and update the react hook with the previous value (need previous file path and new file path should be there).**

problem is when I try to capture a new image and update the useState, the useState hook re-render the view, It'll delete the previous file path and stored a new file path.

I'm suffering from this issue, Please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
 const tempArray = [];
    const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
            
    // capturing the image --------------
    const chooseFile = () => {
        const options = {
            title: 'Select an option',
            storageOptions: {
                 skipBackup: true,
                 path: 'images',
            },
        };
            
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        // console.log('Response = ', response);
        if (response.didCancel) {
           console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
           onsole.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else {
        // let source = response;
        // You can also display the image using data:
            let source = {
               uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data
            };
           createImageArray(source);
     }
    });
 };
            
            const createImageArray = (imageData: string) => {
        // adding file path to temp array -> to get the selected images
                    tempArray.push(imageData);
                    setImagesToHooks();
                    console.log("tempArray.length : " + tempArray.length);
                }
            
                const setImagesToHooks = () => {
                    const imagesArray = Array.from(tempArray).map((result) => result);
                    console.log('images : ' + JSON.stringify(imagesArray));
        // adding mapped array to state hook
                    setSelectedFiles(imagesArray);
                }
```

Comment: update your code, pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find which image picker you were using. But I did understood the problem that the issue was regarding updating the array.

The problem is you are using a second variable to store previous file paths whereas you can use state itself to access previous file path.

Es6 introduced the new concept of [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
You can learn more about this concept through this [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-spread-operator).

Code Reference:

```
    const App = () => {
      const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
      const chooseFile = () => {
        const options = {
          title: 'Select an option',
          storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'images',
          },
        };
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
          if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
          } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
          } else {
            let source = {
              uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data,
            };
            setImagesToHooks(source);
          }
        });
      };
      const setImagesToHooks = (newImage) => {
        // This will update the array. Refer the blog link for more information.
        let imagesArray = [...selectedFiles, newImage];
        setSelectedFiles(imagesArray);
      };

      // Return your code below
      return <React.Fragment/>
    };
```

Since the new update is dependent on previous state, so even after re-render the state is maintained and previous paths retain.

Note: I wasn't able to run the code since the package for image picker was not mentioned.

If you need you can use the below mentioned pickers for react native.

1. [react-native-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker)
2. [react-native-document-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker)